# Why does Python's zipfile create empty folders with no content?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, unzip, python-zipfile

I am working on a Google Colab notebook. I have downloaded datasets from Kaggle and it is in zip format. I have used Python's `zipfile` module but I don't see it working. Looks like it just created empty folders but I don't see contents in it. However, the original `zip` does have content in it.

Screenshot:
[image]

Update: Based on `@Hanna` answer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GoogleColab I always use

`!unzip "test.zip"`

you can use Linux commands by adding a "!" to the beginning of the cell, for more info visit [examples](https://github.com/ipython/ipython-in-depth/blob/b2f9442aa52118dec44ccb0ee749ea63ac578bba//examples/IPython%20Kernel/Beyond%20Plain%20Python.ipynb)

Update

`unzip zip-file-name.zip -d /path/to/directory`

Comment: Wow! this seems to be working. I just updated my answer. Looks like it is unzipping into the contents into some unknown or temporary memory. I don't see them on drive. How do I create a folder called `test` and move them there?

Comment: Thanks for letting me that `!` uses linux commands. I did not know this though I did use it in my code. Can we use bash script code as well? for instance in the above case I tried `!mov 'train' | !unzip 'train.zip'`. But it did not work.

Comment: Guess what! `!unzip "test.zip"` is correct one. It actually unzips, creates a folder called `test` and stores init. `!unzip "test.zip" -d "test"` actually creates test folder inside test folder.